# Red5 cannot display video in Adobe AIR

Tags: air, adobe, red5

I have an Adobe AIR application that I am using to stream some video using RED5. The AIR application has the following Flex code:

```
<s:VideoDisplay id="vidBox" autoPlay="true" autoRewind="true" x="6" y="11" width="95%" height="90%" scaleMode="zoom">
    <s:source>
        <s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource host="rtmp://localhost/TestMovie" streamType="recorded">
            <s:DynamicStreamingVideoItem streamName="2hourmovie.flv" /> 
        </s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource>
    </s:source>
</s:VideoDisplay>
```

When I run the Air Application, I am seeing a rather pretty set of flickering and changing colors instead of the movie. The sound, amazingly, comes through very well.

I use the exact same code in a web- based application, and the movie plays without problems. I see picture and sound and all is well.

I suspect that there is something wrong with AIR that is screwing up the picture, or perhaps I am interacting with AIR in a less- than- correct manner? Or I have found a bug in either AIR or RED5?

Someone please advise. I am using Red5 v1.0.1, Adobe AIR v3.7, and am developing in Flex Builder 4.6.

UPDATE:

More information about this problem: It appears to occur only with very large FLV files. I included some 1- hour movies in my streams directory and ran the AIR application, and the movies displayed without problems. Other files of longer length have the same display failure. Note that the failure does *not* occur in the web browsers, regardless of FLV file size.

Apparently, AIR has some limitation that prevents it from properly displaying FLVs beyond a certain length. Either that, or an AIR application must handle longer FLVs differently from shorter ones. I am uncertain and cannot find any documentation on this matter.

I am working to narrow down how large a file is required to make an AIR video object fail.

Have I found a bug in Adobe AIR? Or is there some coding or configuration I need to adjust in order to make a viewer work properly with larger FLV files?

Someone please advise...